# Update to Xcode 8 Shows Error- "Use Legacy Swift Language Version”

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoapods

I have updated to `XCode 8` and I am getting the following error.

> Alamofire “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is
>   required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use
>   the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift
>   version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build
>   setting directly.

[image]

I searched a lot but didn't get a convenient solution !

Comment: Did you tried to update your pods?

Comment: You have to update Swift : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613758/upgrade-xcode-7-3-1-project-to-xcode-8-0/39614742?noredirect=1#comment66537202_39614742

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue

Comment: Duplicate for Xcode-8.1 :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue/40482708#40482708